# dplyr - arrange, group, compute difference in dates

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset showing a follow-up of kids from a "healthy" event to subsequent "sick" events

I am trying to use dplyr to compute time between "healthy" event and first "sick" event

**simulated dataset**

```
 id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1) 
event <- c("healthy","","","sick","sick","")
date_follow_up <- c("4/1/15", "4/2/15", "4/3/15", "4/4/15", "4/5/15", "4/6/15")

df1 <- data_frame(id, event, date_follow_up)
```

**simulated output dataset**

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1) 
event <- c("healthy","","","sick","sick","")
date_follow_up <- c("4/1/15", "4/2/15", "4/3/15", "4/4/15", "4/5/15", "4/6/15")
diff_time <- c(3,"","","","","")

df1 <- data_frame(id, event, date_follow_up, diff_time)
```

I've only been able to go as far as use dplyr to sort the data by "id" and "date_follow_up" then group by "id":

```
df2 <- df1 %>% arrange(id, date_follow_up) %>% group_by(id)
```

Kindly need help in computing the difference in date and adding it next to the row with the "healthy" event for each individual :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your data a bit more to examine this case thoroughly. My suggestion is similar to what alistaire suggested. My suggestion can produce NA for id 2 in `mydf`, whereas alistaire suggestion creates Inf. First, I converted your dates (in character) to Date objects.Then, I grouped the data by `id`, and calculated time difference by subtracting the first day of `healthy` (i.e., `date_follow_up[event == "healthy"][1]`) from the first day of `sick` (i.e., `date_follow_up[event == "sick"][1]`). Finally, I replaced the time difference with NA for irrelevant rows.

```
   id   event date_follow_up
1   1 healthy         4/1/15
2   1                 4/2/15
3   1                 4/3/15
4   1    sick         4/4/15
5   1    sick         4/5/15
6   2                 4/1/15
7   2 healthy         4/2/15
8   2                 4/3/15
9   2                 4/4/15
10  2                 4/5/15
11  3                 4/1/15
12  3 healthy         4/2/15
13  3    sick         4/3/15
14  3                 4/4/15
15  3                 4/5/15

library(dplyr)
mutate(mydf, date_follow_up = as.Date(date_follow_up, format = "%m/%d/%y")) %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(foo = date_follow_up[event == "sick"][1] - date_follow_up[event == "healthy"][1],        
       foo = replace(foo, which(event != "healthy"), NA))


Source: local data frame [15 x 4]
Groups: id [3]

      id   event date_follow_up            foo
   <int>   <chr>         <date> <S3: difftime>
1      1 healthy     2015-04-01         3 days
2      1             2015-04-02        NA days
3      1             2015-04-03        NA days
4      1    sick     2015-04-04        NA days
5      1    sick     2015-04-05        NA days
6      2             2015-04-01        NA days
7      2 healthy     2015-04-02        NA days
8      2             2015-04-03        NA days
9      2             2015-04-04        NA days
10     2             2015-04-05        NA days
11     3             2015-04-01        NA days
12     3 healthy     2015-04-02         1 days
13     3    sick     2015-04-03        NA days
14     3             2015-04-04        NA days
15     3             2015-04-05        NA days
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), event = c("healthy", "", "", "sick", "sick", 
"", "healthy", "", "", "", "", "healthy", "sick", "", ""), date_follow_up = c("4/1/15", 
"4/2/15", "4/3/15", "4/4/15", "4/5/15", "4/1/15", "4/2/15", "4/3/15", 
"4/4/15", "4/5/15", "4/1/15", "4/2/15", "4/3/15", "4/4/15", "4/5/15"
)), .Names = c("id", "event", "date_follow_up"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Jazzurro, just like Akrun's, I appreciate the consideration for multiple healthy/sick events and how you catered for other id's. Let me see how the "real" data responds. Cheers

Comment: @K.Kariuki Pleasure oto help you.

Answer (score 3):

Using @akrun's example data, here's one way using *rolling joins* from *data.table*:

```
require(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(mydf)[, date_follow_up := as.Date(date_follow_up, format="%m/%d/%y")][]
dt1 = dt[event == "healthy"]
dt2 = dt[event == "sick"]

idx = dt2[dt1, roll = -Inf, which = TRUE, on = c("id", "date_follow_up")]
```

The idea is: for every healthy date (in `dt1`), get the index of first sick date (in `dt2`) `>=` the healthy date.

Then it's straightforward to subtract the two dates to get the final result.

```
dt[event == "healthy", 
     diff := as.integer(dt2$date_follow_up[idx] - dt1$date_follow_up)]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback, on running the last line of code, I get the error:      Error in `[.data.table`(dt2, dt1, roll = -Inf, which = TRUE, on = .(id,  : 
  could not find function "."

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(mydf)`), change the class of 'date_follow_up to `Date` using `as.Date`, grouped by 'id' and a grouping variable created by getting the cumulative sum of logical vector (`event == "healthy"`), we get the difference of 'date_follow_up' for the first "sick" 'event' with the first 'date_follow_up' (which would be "healthy") `if` there are `any` "sick" 'event' in that particular group or `else` return "NA".

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, date_follow_up := as.Date(date_follow_up, "%m/%d/%y")
    ][, foo := if(any(event == "sick"))  
                  as.integer(date_follow_up[which(event=="sick")[1]] - 
                         date_follow_up[1] )
                else NA_integer_ , 
     by = .(grp= cumsum(event == "healthy"), id)]
```

Then, we can change the "foo" to "NA" for all "event" that are not "healthy".

```
mydf[event!= "healthy", foo := NA_integer_]
mydf
#    id   event date_follow_up foo
# 1:  1 healthy     2015-04-01   3
# 2:  1             2015-04-02  NA
# 3:  1             2015-04-03  NA
# 4:  1    sick     2015-04-04  NA
# 5:  1    sick     2015-04-05  NA
# 6:  2             2015-04-01  NA
# 7:  2 healthy     2015-04-02  NA
# 8:  2             2015-04-03  NA
# 9:  2             2015-04-04  NA
#10:  2             2015-04-05  NA
#11:  3             2015-04-01  NA
#12:  3 healthy     2015-04-02   1
#13:  3    sick     2015-04-03  NA
#14:  3             2015-04-04  NA
#15:  3             2015-04-05  NA
#16:  4             2015-04-01  NA
#17:  4 healthy     2015-04-02   3
#18:  4             2015-04-03  NA
#19:  4             2015-04-04  NA
#20:  4    sick     2015-04-05  NA
#21:  4    sick     2015-04-06  NA
#22:  4             2015-04-07  NA
#23:  4 healthy     2015-04-08   2
#24:  4             2015-04-09  NA
#25:  4    sick     2015-04-10  NA
```

NOTE: Here, I prepared data where there can be multiple "healthy/sick" 'event' possible for a particular "id".

#### data

```
mydf <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), event = c("healthy", "", 
"", "sick", "sick", "", "healthy", "", "", "", "", "healthy", 
"sick", "", "", "", "healthy", "", "", "sick", "sick", "", "healthy", 
"", "sick"), date_follow_up = c("4/1/15", "4/2/15", "4/3/15", 
"4/4/15", "4/5/15", "4/1/15", "4/2/15", "4/3/15", "4/4/15", "4/5/15", 
"4/1/15", "4/2/15", "4/3/15", "4/4/15", "4/5/15", "4/1/15", "4/2/15", 
"4/3/15", "4/4/15", "4/5/15", "4/6/15", "4/7/15", "4/8/15", "4/9/15", 
"4/10/15")), .Names = c("id", "event", "date_follow_up"), row.names = c(NA, 
25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You further considered possible cases. Plus one back to you. :)

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks, yes I was a bit curious whether my first solution works for it and it didn't.

Comment: @akrun I believe the OP has enough things to consider how he/she solve the puzzle.

Comment: Hi Akrun, thanks, and for the consideration of multiple healthy/sick events. Much appreciated. Now to see how the "real" data responds :)

Comment: hi @akrun, I have tried it on the larger dataset and it works perfectly. However, I need to make some adjustments. So far, the script looks for **first** "sick" event that follows each "healthy" event for each individual. Kindly assist me in tweaking to: _for every individual, sort entries by date and if the first entry is "healthy", then find the first sick event that follows and get the difference in dates. It should not consider additional "healthy" events that follow_

Comment: @K.Kariuki  What do you meant by the first entry is `healthy`?  FOr ordering by date column, 'date_follow_up' can be used in the `i` i.e. `setDT(mydf)[, date_follow_up := as.Date(date_follow_up, "%m/%d/%y")[order(date_follow_up), ..`  Did you meant the first observation as 'healthy' in a 'id' (after ordering by 'date_follow_up')?  Can you post this as a new question?

Comment: Ok, let me post it as new question and add more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach, though you may need to adapt it to become more robust if you have multiple "healthy" events per ID:

```
        # turn dates into subtractable Date class
df1 %>% mutate(date_follow_up = as.Date(date_follow_up, '%m/%d/%y')) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
           # Add new column. If there is a "healthy" event,
    mutate(diff_time = ifelse(event == 'healthy', 
                              # subtract the date from the minimum "sick" date
                              min(date_follow_up[event == 'sick']) - date_follow_up, 
                              # else if it isn't a "healthy" event, return NA.
                              NA))

## Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
## 
##      id   event date_follow_up diff_time
##   <dbl>   <chr>         <date>     <dbl>
## 1     1 healthy     2015-04-01         3
## 2     1             2015-04-02        NA
## 3     1             2015-04-03        NA
## 4     1    sick     2015-04-04        NA
## 5     1    sick     2015-04-05        NA
## 6     1             2015-04-06        NA
```

Comment: Hi, Alistare. Thanks for the feedback. Akrun and Jazzurro catered for multiple "healthy events". Still, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using `dplyr` (although it's a bit longer compared to the earlier solution)

```
library(dplyr)
df1$date_follow_up <- as.Date(df1$date_follow_up, "%m/%d/%y")

df1 %>% group_by(id, event) %>%
        filter(event %in% c("healthy", "sick")) %>%
        slice(which.min(date_follow_up)) %>% group_by(id) %>%
        mutate(diff_time = lead(date_follow_up) - date_follow_up) %>% 
        right_join(df1, by = c("id", "event" , "date_follow_up"))

# Output 

Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: id [?]

      id   event   date_follow_up       diff_time
     <dbl>   <chr>         <date>  <S3: difftime>
1     1   healthy     2015-04-01         3 days
2     1               2015-04-02        NA days
3     1               2015-04-03        NA days
4     1      sick     2015-04-04        NA days    
5     1      sick     2015-04-05        NA days
6     1               2015-04-06        NA days
```

Comment: Hi Sumedh, thanks. I tested it on the original dataset I posted and it works well. I then tested in on Akrun's dataset, which is similar to the "real" data I have (multiple healthy/sick events) and it fails with this error:Warning message:
In right_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining character vector and factor, coercing into character vector. Still much appreciated..